# Gitlab CI and Git partial clone

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, monorepo, sparse-checkout

I am testing the git partial clone feature on a large monorepo. A developer might run the following commands on his machine:

```
git clone --filter=blob:none --sparse THE_MONOREPO_URL.git
git sparse-checkout init --cone 
git sparse-checkout set SOME FOLDERS
```

This seems to be working well, and I am now trying to get CI up and running in Gitlab. If I use the default settings in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, Gitlab clones the entire monorepo, which takes forever.

Gitlab recently added experimental support for partial clones, but is there any support in Gitlab-CI? Is my only option to use `GIT_STRATEGY: none` and then clone everything manually in the `before_script` using the commands above?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `clone --sparse` has already run `sparse-checkout init` for you.

You can set the git strategy to FETCH, then use https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#git-fetch-extra-flags to custom how you fetch/clone your project.

Note that Fetch and Clone strategy both use this flag. The only different between the 2 strategy is that Clone would attempt to remove what ever left of the repo cached from the previous run before running 'git fetch'

Answer (score -1):

You can configure GitLab CI to make a shallow clone. Go to your project page - Settings - CI/CD, expand General pipelines, and insert a value to Git shallow clone field.

Comment: That's correct, but not the answer to the OP's question.